# How do I assign drivers with the eyedropper?

Tags: drivers, graph-editor

I cannot figure out how to assign drivers with the eyedropper. I try clicking on the mesh I want to be the Driver but instead of working the eyedropper just disappears. I have gone to *Graph Editor> Drivers* and no drivers have shown up.

Comment: Drivers are picked from other properties in the UI, not directly from objects, as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

You click with the left mouse button on  the eyedropper and then with left mouse button (yes both times with Left mouse button) on the mesh, which you want to be driving one. If that doesn't work, reinstall your Blender, cause there is no way it shouldn't.